# Mutually overlapping opaque arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

I have drawn a circle with two arrow shapes on top of it, and now I want the arrows to be mutually overlapping, i.e. the blue arrow's head should be above the red arrow's tail (which it is), and the red arrow's head should be above the blue arrow's tail (which it isn't). How can I achieve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{mainstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!40,minimum size=20}}
\tikzset{spinarrow/.style={single arrow,draw,opacity=0.8,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=0.5cm,scale=0.6}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mainstyle] (a) at (0,0) {\(x\)};

  \foreach \angle in {20,40,...,360}
  {
    \draw [black,arrows={-latex[black]}] (a.\angle) -- +(\angle:1cm);
  }

  \node [spinarrow,fill=red!50,shape border rotate=90] at (-0.2,0) {\(+\)};
  \node [spinarrow,fill=blue!50,shape border rotate=270] at (0.2,0) {\(-\)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does scoping `\begin{scope}[transparency group]....\end{scope}` help?

Comment: @percusse do you want to provide an answer? I can delete mine.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Of course not :) I just scribbled there without being sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option using a `transparency group` and redrawing the red arrow tip after the blue arrow has been drawn:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{mainstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!40,minimum size=20}}
\tikzset{spinarrow/.style={single arrow,draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=0.5cm,scale=0.6}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mainstyle] (a) at (0,0) {\(x\)};

  \foreach \angle in {20,40,...,360}
  {
    \draw [black,arrows={-latex[black]}] (a.\angle) -- +(\angle:1cm);
  }

\begin{scope}[opacity=0.8,transparency group]
  \node [spinarrow,fill=red!50,shape border rotate=90] at (-0.2,0) (plus) {\(+\)};
  \node [spinarrow,fill=blue!50,shape border rotate=270] at (0.2,0) {\(-\)};
  \draw[fill=red!50] 
    (plus.after head) --
    (plus.after tip) --
    (plus.tip) --
    (plus.before tip) --
    (plus.before head);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another attempt with less coding, i.e., use of `clip` to redraw the red head again.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{mainstyle/.style={circle,draw,fill=gray!40,minimum size=20}}
\tikzset{spinarrow/.style={single arrow,draw,opacity=0.8,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=0.5cm,scale=0.6}}

\begin{document}

OP's solution:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mainstyle] (a) at (0,0) {\(x\)};

  \foreach \angle in {20,40,...,360}
  {
    \draw [black,arrows={-latex}] (a.\angle) -- +(\angle:1cm);
  }

  \node [spinarrow,fill=red!50,shape border rotate=90] at (-0.2,0) {\(+\)};
  \node [spinarrow,fill=blue!50,shape border rotate=270] at (0.2,0) {\(-\)};

\end{tikzpicture}

Proposed solution:

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mainstyle] (a) at (0,0) {\(x\)};

  \foreach \angle in {20,40,...,360}
  {
    \draw [black,arrows={-latex}] (a.\angle) -- +(\angle:1cm);
  }

\node [spinarrow,fill=red!50,shape border rotate=90] at (-0.2,0) {\(+\)};
\node [spinarrow,fill=blue!50,shape border rotate=270] at (0.2,0) {\(-\)};
\begin{scope}          %  new code here
\clip (-0.5,0) rectangle (0.2,1);
\node [spinarrow,fill=red!50,shape border rotate=90] at (-0.2,0) {\(+\)};
\end{scope}            % new code here
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```